# How might I return multiple arrays with equal values from a larger array with mixed values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, string-matching, array-push

I have an array that *after being sorted* appears like this:

```
var arr = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"];
```

There are 2 `"a"` Strings, 4 `"b"` Strings, and 3 `"c"` Strings.

I am trying to return 3 separate arrays, returning them one at a time from a loop, containing **only** matching values. So, upon the first iteration, the returned array would appear as `newArr = ["a", "a"]`,  the second as `newArr = ["b", "b", "b", "b"]`  and on the third iteration as `newArr = ["c", "c", "c"]`.  

However, this is a small array of predefined values, and I need an algorithm that can perform the same operation on an array of *unknown* size, *unknown* elements, and with an *unknown* number of like elements. (and keep in mind that the array is already sorted to begin with, in this context)

Here's my crazy code that is displaying some unusual, and incorrect, results:

```
var arr = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"];

for(var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++)
{
  var test = "";
  var newArr = []; // resets the new array upon each iteration
  var str = arr[index]; // initialized as the next unique index-value

  for(var i = index; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    if(arr[i] == str)
    {
      newArr.push(arr[k]);
      test += arr[i] + " ";
    }
    else
    {
      index = i; // changing the outer loop variable
      break; // exiting the inner loop
    }
  } // end of inner loop

  window.alert(test);
  setValues(newArr);

} // end of outer loop

function setValues(arrSorted)
{
  var here = document.getElementById("here");

  for(var i = 0; i < arrSorted.length; i++)
  {
    here.innerHTML += arrSorted[i] + "&nbsp;";
  }

  here.innerHTML += "<br />";

} // end of setValues function
```

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify whether `["a","a","b","b","a","a"]` would return `[["a","a"],["b","b"],["a","a"]]` or `[["a","a","a","a"],["b","b"]]`, and whether you expect the function input to be sorted like your first array.

Comment: In the example you have given, `["a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a"]` should return 2 arrays:  `["a", "a", "a", "a",]`,  and `["b", "b"]`.

Comment: And I have a function that is sorting the array, not mentioned above, but the array will be sorted before splitting it into several arrays ya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arr = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"];
var arrays = {};
for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
  if (!arrays[arr[i]]) arrays[arr[i]] = [];
  arrays[arr[i]].push(arr[i]);
}
```

this will give you the equivalent of

```
arrays = {};
arrays['a'] = ['a','a'];
arrays['b'] = ['b','b','b','b','b'];
arrays['c'] = ['c','c','c'];
```

Comment: This is a very elegant and concise solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like this to divide the array into several arrays:

```
function divide(arr) {

  var subArrays = [];
  var current = null;
  var subArray = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] != current) {
      if (subArray != null) subArrays.push(subArray);
      current = arr[i];
      subArray = [];
    }
    subArray.push(arr[i]);
  }
  if (subArray != null) subArrays.push(subArray);
  return subArrays;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/d8CBD/

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
var arr = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"];

var out = [], prev;
for (var i = 0, j = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== prev || !out.length) {
        out[j++] = [prev = arr[i]];
    } else {
        out[j - 1].push(prev);
    }
}

//out -> [["a","a"],["b","b","b"],["c","c","c"]]
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eM9Et/)

**Note:** the `|| !out.length` check is just handle arrays that start with `undefined` correctly, but feel free to remove it if this will never be the case